# gradle difference between packageDebug and assembleDebug

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

Both `gradlew packageDebug` and `gradlew assembleDebug` will create my APK.  `assembleDebug` appears to rely on `packageDebug`, so what else is it doing for me?  Is there some reason I should be using one or the other?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you run the gradle tasks:

```
gradle packageDebug --info
gradle assembleDebug --info
```

the secuence of gradle tasks executed are the same, except one, the last:

```
zipalignDebug
```

And referencing to [zipalign](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/zipalign.html), this task perform optimizations on apk file. This process is carried out once generated and signed the apk. That's why when you run on the two tasks, you see a generated apk file.

Answer (score 1):

Use `assembleDebug`, it's NOT equivalent to `packageDebug`. `assembleDebug` contains `packageDebug` and perform other tasks as well.

Below you will find a list of all tasks included in `assembleDebug`, one of them is `packageDebug`.

```
app:assembleDebug - Assembles all Debug builds
    app:checkDebugManifest
    app:compileDebugAidl
    app:compileDebugJava
    app:compileDebugNdk
    app:compileDebugRenderscript
    app:dexDebug      
    app:generateDebugAssets
    app:generateDebugBuildConfig
    app:generateDebugResValues
    app:generateDebugResources
    app:generateDebugSources
    app:mergeDebugAssets
    app:mergeDebugResources
    app:packageDebug  
    app:preBuild      
    app:preDebugBuild 
    app:preDexDebug   
    app:preReleaseBuild
    app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV132000Library - Prepare com.android.support:support-v13:20.0.0
    app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42000Library - Prepare com.android.support:support-v4:20.0.0
    app:prepareDebugDependencies
    app:processDebugJavaRes
    app:processDebugManifest
    app:processDebugResources
    app:validateDebugSigning
    app:zipalignDebug
```

Additionally, from the Gradle Plugin documentation:

> An Android project has at least two outputs: a debug APK and a release
>   APK. Each of these has its own anchor task to facilitate building them
>   separately:

```
- assemble
   - assembleDebug
   - assembleRelease
```

> They both depend on other tasks that execute the multiple steps needed
>   to build an APK. The assemble task depends on both, so calling it will
>   build both APKs

Comment: Why does assembleDebug call preReleaseBuild? (none of the other dependent tasks have Release in their name)

Comment: I am not sure. It seems that every build takes into account other build types for the very initial steps. assembleRelease call preDebugBuild too. If you run a task with -profile flag and open HTML report you will notice that these unexpected steps take no time, actually profile report says that it did not work

Comment: How did you find out which tasks are included with assembleDebug?

Comment: @dazza5000 just type `./gradlew tasks --all` in Android Studio terminal